# Getting [object Object] after getting http response using subscribe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-routing, angular-services

ProductService.ts

```
   getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {

    return this._http.get(this._productUrl + '/GetById/' + 
           id).map((response: Response) => <IProduct>response.json())           
        .catch(this.errorHandler);     
}
```

ProductDetailComponent.ts

```
   getProduct(id: number) {
    this._productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(
        res => {               
            console.log('before component ' + res);     
            this.product = res;
            console.log('after component ' + res);                
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error),
        console.log('execution complete'); 
}
```

When receiving result in subscribe it is coming as
   execution complete, 
   before component [object Object], 
   after component [object Object]

Comment: console.log('before component ' + JSON.stringify(res));

Comment: @Shota do `console.log(JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2))` to pretty print

Comment: Thanks, console.log('before component ', res); is also another option.

Comment: Also why are you printing `res` before and after? its value doesnt look like it changed?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do JSON.stringify

```
console.log('before component ' + JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using string concatenation (using the `+` sign). This way, Javascript will first convert the Object to a string (`[object Object]`). If you don't want that, you could try it like this: `console.log('before component', res)`.

Note the comma, not a `+`. This passes the object to `console.log` as a separate parameter, allowing your browser or CLI to do the rendering. For instance, this way (in the browser) you can expand or collapse the object.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
console.log('before component',JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2))
```

to pretty print `[Object object]` as json object.

Comment: But still i am not able to get desired result in this.product object.      
                                                                                                        
   before component {
  "productId": 1,
  "productName": "Garden Cart",
  "productCode": "GDN-0023",
  "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
  "price": 32.99,
  "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
  "starRating": 4.2,
  "imageUrl": "app/Images/a.png"
}product-detail.component.ts:38 after component [object Object]                             console.log('after component ' +  this.product);

Comment: what are you getting and what are you expecting? print using JSON.stringify after also

Comment: i need to bind json result to product object

Comment: As I said use `console.log('after component',JSON.stringify(this.product,undefined,2))`

Comment: But when doing this                                                                                                               this.product =  JSON.stringify(this.product,undefined,2);                                              i am getting this error "string is not assignable to type IProduct"

Comment: what? no that is printing value.. you can set the value normally `this.product = res`

Comment: thts not working as i posted my question                                                                     values inside this.product when bind to html it showing undefined

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined in html

Comment: may be it happen because html is rendering before response come